# Install unity 7.1.2 in ubuntu 12.04, is possible?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 13.04, downgrade, interface

I have upgraded Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. I like very more the default unity interface. The command `unity --version` return `unity 7.1.2`.

The problem in Ubuntu 13.10 is than I give errors on installation php5, mysql, I have found than I need to use 12.04 if I want to run on it apache2, php5, mysql, phpmyadmin.

If I install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop I use the latest version of Unity? If yes, how?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Regretfully no! The last version of Unity is for last version of Ubuntu, because this I use Fedora with Gnome Shell now. I think that Ubuntu 14.04 will run rightly all programs.